# Azure Data Factory: How to convert UTC datetime to unix Timestamp

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to convert UTC datetime to unix Timestamp? example: 2021-11-08T07:25:00Z to 1636385119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **In ADF Pipeline:**

```
@{div(sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks('1970-01-01')),10000000)}
```

[image]

[image]

### **In Data flow:**

As explained here in doc: [Convert to dates or timestamps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#convert-to-dates-or-timestamps)

```
toLong( currentUTC() - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') ) * 1000l
```